# sum of case when in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate

I am trying convert hql script into pyspark. I am struggling how to achieve sum of case when statements in aggregation after groupby clause. eg.

```
dataframe1 = dataframe0.groupby(col0).agg(
            SUM(f.when((col1 == 'ABC' | col2 == 'XYZ'), 1).otherwise(0)))
```

Is it possible in pyspark?
I am getting error while executing such statement.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use withColumn to create a column with the values you want to to be summed, then aggregate on that.  For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('key', T.IntegerType(), True),
    T.StructField('col1', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('col2', T.StringType(), True)
])

data = [
    (1, 'ABC', 'DEF'),
    (1, 'DEF', 'XYZ'),
    (1, 'DEF', 'GHI')
]

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)



result = df.withColumn('value', F.when((df.col1 == 'ABC') | (df.col2 == 'XYZ'), 1).otherwise(0)) \
           .groupBy('key') \
              .agg(F.sum('value').alias('sum'))

result.show(100, False)
```

Which prints out this result:

```
+---+---+
|key|sum|
+---+---+
|1  |2  |
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! withColumn helped me and am able to perform sum now.. :)